# comprasion two chars causes timeout: the monitored command dumped core

Tags: c, char

I try to find the distance between two char arrays by a recursive function.
     Firstly look my run.c and lab_2_0_copy.h

run.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lab_2_0.h"
const char characters[10]={'A','N','E','X','A','M','P','L','E','!'};


int main(){

    find_distance_between_strings(characters);
    return 0;
}
```

lab_2_o_copy.h

```
#ifndef _LAB_2_0_
#define _LAB_2_0_

const char characters[10];

char read_character();
void find_distance_between_strings(char b[]);
void helper(char a[],char b[],int i,int c);


#endif
```

and lab_2_0.c which includes implementations of my functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lab_2_0.h"

char read_character(){
    char data;
    scanf(" %c",&data);
    return data;
}

/* TASK SOLUTIONS */

int helper(char a[],char b[],int i,int c)
{
 if(i<10)
 {
     a[i]=read_character();
     if(a[i]!=b[i])
     {
         c++;
     }
 }
}
void find_distance_between_strings(char b[])
{
    char a[10];
    helper(a,b,0,0);


}
```

I am aware of the fact that my implementations are not complete , it seems that the if statement which includes a[i]!=b[i] causes SEGV but I am not sure because when I delete operation of incrementing of c The code does not cause SEGV or the monitored command dumped core I do not know what my fault is .

Comment: Compiler warnings aside, I'm [not able to reproduce the problem](https://repl.it/repls/DimpledUnwillingScientificcomputing).

Comment: Problem wouldn't be reproduced as there is nothing that is using variable 'c'. Possibly, there was a[i]!=b[c] or something that causes problem. 
Anyway, it appears that the index needs to be checked for out of bounds.

Comment: Since this is a homework (not my homework though I was just curious if I could solve that problem or not ) , I am writing this code online , can it be due to this ? @ggorlen

Comment: Tip for newbie @nooneever, use @ to specify who is the comment for :)

also, why not paste the online code link for people to try. Something like ideone.com

Comment: @Abhinav I agree with you , it seems that the problem is caused by a[i]!=b[i] but I do not have any idea why .

Comment: I still think your code needs i++ rather than c++ to reproduce problem

Comment: I don't see any bounds issues in the code you posted. `a` and `b` are both populated at index 0, which is the only value `i` ever has.

Comment: Looks like we need to speculate and make the code to fault and then propose solution :D

Comment: Also,you are passing a const char[] to a function taking char[]. Does this even comple without errors?

Comment: @Abhinav Since the link requires an account of my department , I now will try to compile the code on the online compiler of my department if the same error occurs I will give you a link :)

Comment: @Abhinav that was the problem,passing const char[] to a function taking char [], as it is stated in the answer , thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your helper function prototype in the "lab_2_0.h" file doesn't match the function definition prototype in the "lab_2_0.c" file.

it should be either:

```
void helper(char a[],char b[],int i,int c);
```

in both files or

```
int helper(char a[],char b[],int i,int c);
```

Next, if you choose

```
int helper(char a[],char b[],int i,int c);
```

you need to provide a return in this function.

Next point is that your array of characters[10] is const. This const qualifier is removed when you call the find_distance_between_strings function. This has the potential to cause errors as you are not allowed to modify const variables.

To fix it, change the prototype of find_distance_between_strings to the following (in both the .h and the .c file):

```
find_distance_between_strings(const char b[]);
```

To further follow this up, you need to further change the helper function prototype to the following (in both, the .h and .c files):

```
int helper(char a[], const char b[],int i, int c);
```

The last thing is that there is no recursion in your program as it currently stands.

Comment: The main problem was  passing  passing a const char[] to a function taking char[] as it was stated by @Abhinav , My function were recursive but when I took that SEGV  error I changed it to examine the error . Thank you  everyone commented/answered here :)